# Swift Firebase changing value is unstable

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I'm trying to change the value in Firebase, using TableView.

And Here is the Swift code in didSelectRowAt.

```
if let result = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] {

for child in result {

    let nameDB = child.childSnapshot(forPath: "contactName").value! as! String

    if nameDB == receiverName {

          let autoID = child.key as String

          if receiverAmount.characters.contains("-") {

              self.dbRef.child("user/contacts/\(autoID)/borrowAmount").setValue("")
              self.dbRef.child("user/contacts/\(autoID)/borrowDueDate").setValue("")
          }
          else {

              self.dbRef.child("user/contacts/\(autoID)/lendAmount").setValue("")
              self.dbRef.child("user/contacts/\(autoID)/lendDueDate").setValue("2099-12-31")
          }
```

But While my app is, Values are unstable.

Original value and new value are endlessly changed, and then my app is stopped.

Any idea for solving this problem...?

Thank you!!

Comment: You just want to update the value of a single child and single value in that respected child  ? is it ?

Comment: @iOSGeek Yes It is..

Comment: Do you have all the details to path of respected value in database ? like Child ID , Child name , Value name to be updated before this for loop ? or you are getting these details from For loop ?

Comment: As you are using a tableView I am sure you are having al values required even if you do not use for loop ? instead using for loop on didselectAction just perform value update directly by creating a reference not using for loop

Comment: @iOSGeek Thanks for replying! Now I got it what you said.. Why I'm using for loop is in the Firebase, I have multiple values and inside each values, there are what I want to update. 

And My logic is : Select one of the tableView -> get name from tableView -> match name in the Firebase using for loop -> then update values with details

Should i update my Firebase JSON for more clear...?

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I mean As you are using here a Loop Which will Automatically refer to endless update til for loop condition is not satisfied , So should I Set this points as Answer to question ?

Comment: @iOSGeek Then I should get them out from for loop..... OK I appreciate it.

Comment: Yes , you must get that out from Loop As you are performing task on DIdSelect Function You have all values so No need of loop there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) As you are using a tableView I am sure you are having al values required even if you do not use for loop ? instead using for loop on didselectAction just perform value update directly by creating a reference not using for loop.

2)Due to for loop Condition you are getting unstable outputs So, Just avoid for loop here and Directly update values